# org html exporter case sensitivity of links

Tags: org-mode, org-export

if I have an org file like this:

```
this is [[heading]]
* Heading
```

I can follow "Heading" with 'C-c C-o' so the link and the target are case insensitive.

However if I try to export this org file to html (org-export-to-html) I get this error:

> user-error: Unable to resolve link "heading"

which means that for html exporter the link and the target are case sensitive. Is there a way to make it case insensitive?